# Background images flickering in a SpriteKit app using Swift

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have several layers of background, midground, foreground, ground, etc in a sprite kit app.

I have managed to get them to loop around but the trouble is that when they load they flicker and do not transition smoothly from one image to another.

I also had an issue with a gap appearing between the images but this was resolved by adding one extra pixel to the width of each.

The flickering doesn't happen every time and it loops and there doesn't seem to be any relation to how the images are sized (to frame or view), removing the extra pixel from the width, changing the speed, changing the device, etc.

Also, Z positions are ok and the ignore sibling order in the game view controller makes no effect in resolving it.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?  Is there anything in my code I have done wrong or are others experiencing similar with SpriteKit?  I cannot find a definitive comparison elsewhere.

Here is a sample of my code that is affected:

In the viewDidLoad:

```
//Declaration of the midground nodes.

var mgImage: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()
var mgImage2: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()
```

In the didMoveToView:

```
    //Creates an instance of both sprites that are of the same image that are to be lined up against each other in the x axis creating the illution of continuity.

    mgImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "CityMid.png")
    mgImage2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "CityMid.png")

    //Specifies the Z position of the images.

    mgImage.zPosition = 1
    mgImage2.zPosition = 1

    //Scales the image to the correct size of the screen.

    mgImage.size.width = self.frame.width + 1
    mgImage.size.height = self.frame.height

    mgImage2.size.width = self.frame.width + 1
    mgImage2.size.height = self.frame.height

    //Specicies the x position of the images.  By offsetting the second you create the illution of a long, continuous image.

    mgImage.position.x = view.bounds.size.width * 0.5
    mgImage2.position.x = view.bounds.size.width * 1.5

    //Specifies the y postion of the images, obviously these are the same as they are not to be offset at any time.

    mgImage.position.y = (self.frame.size.height - self.frame.size.height) + self.mgImage.size.height / 2
    mgImage2.position.y = (self.frame.size.height - self.frame.size.height) + self.mgImage2.size.height / 2

    //Prevents aliasing with other nearby spites.

    mgImage.texture?.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest
    mgImage2.texture?.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest

    //Adds instances of the sprites to the scene.

    self.addChild(mgImage)
    self.addChild(mgImage2)
```

This is also the same for all layers that are listed here and again, speed, etc do not seem to make it better or worse either way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Steven

Answer (score 1):

Am i correct that you want a endlessly moving background with different speed?

I think the flickering happens when there are two image at the same place but the programming doesn't know which needs to be on to so the alternate each other.

PS. This is a answer because i can't comment.

Comment: But do you want it to move left and back to right or just an endlessly moving background?

Comment: Endlessly moving in a smooth loop,  changing speed after a certain number of loops but perfectly smooth with no flicker.

Comment: If your background runs smoothly but it only flickers from time to time. Try to put for each piece of background a other z valuable so the program knows what lies on top. Further rest i can't help you

Comment: self.frame.size.height - self.frame.size.height  You know that this doesn't do anything right?

Comment: No actually,  should it not have height stated?

Comment: Not sure what you mean

Comment: (self.frame.size.height - self.frame.size.height) + self.mgImage.size.height / 2   With This you just get the half of your image because this (self.frame.size.height - self.frame.size.height) ends with 0